# Calculos devaluacion

Tags: java

Reformula una duda que lleva toda la semana y no tengo forma de solucionarlo. El ejercicio me pide lo siguiente:

Calcular la devaluación de un coche a partir de dos parámetros: price, age. La devaluación se calculará a partir de trienios (cada 3 años de antigüedad del coche).

```
Tabla de relacion entre trienios y ratio de amortizacion:

    [0, 1) 0%
    [1, 3) 10%
    [3, 5) 15%
    (5, ∞) 18%

La devaluación se calcula a través de la siguiente formula:

precio = precio * (1 - devaluación)

Ejemplo

Coche 2 años (0 trienos): precio = 5000 * (1 - 0) = 5000€
Coche 3 años (1 trienos): precio = 5000 * (1 - 0.1) = 4500€
Coche 4 años (1 trienos): precio = 5000 * (1 - 0.1) = 4500€

Coche 6 años (2 trienos): 
Primer trienio = precio = 5000 * (1 - 0.1) = 4500€ 
Segundo trienio = precio = 4500 * (1 - 0.1) = 4050€

Coche 9 años (3 trienos): 
Primer trienio = precio = 5000 * (1 - 0.1) = 4500€ 
Segundo trienio = precio = 4500 * (1 - 0.1) = 4050€
tercer trienio = precio = 4050€ * (1 - 0.15) = 3442,5€
```

La idea es hacer un bucle for e ir multiplicando el resultado segun el trienio que sea.

Mi codigo

```
int trienis = age / 3;
        int index = 0;
        while (index <= trienis) {
            if (index <1) {
                price = price * 1;
                index++;
            }
            if (index < 3 && index >= 0) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.1);
                index++;
            }
            if (index > 2 && index < 5) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.15);
                index++;
            }
            if (index > 4) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.18);
                index++;
            }
        }
        return price;
    }
```

No acaba de funcionar del todo ya que no me calcula bien los trienios. Podeis ayudar a encontrar el error.

El resultado no es el correcto. No muestra error, pero tengo un archivo test y no concuerdan los resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu código es que los rangos se solapan, y los rangos TIENEN que ser excluyentes. Por ejemplo, el segundo if que tienes declarado se va a cumplir tanto en el trilenio 0 como para el 1, y eso conlleva a que no te de el resultado correcto. Soluciona eso y todo estará resuelto.

Te adjunto las correcciones:

```
 int trienis = age / 3;
        int index = 0;
        while (index <= trienis) {
            if (index <1) {
                price = price * 1;
            }
            if (index < 3 && index >= 1) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.1);
            }
            if (index >= 3 && index < 5) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.15);
            }
            if (index >= 5) {
                price = price * (1 - 0.18);
            }
             index++;
        }
```

Alternativamente podrías haber implementado un switch para obtener el mismo resultado:

```
 int index = 0;
        while (index <= trienis) {
            switch(index){
                case 0:
                    price = price * 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    price = price * (1-0.1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    price = price * (1-0.15);
                    break;
                default:
                    price = price * (1-0.18);
                    break;
            }
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: Porque el codigo con el while me peta y me dice: "missing return statement"?

Comment: Ponle el return al final... como lo tienes en tu código después de cerrar la llave del while

Comment: funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias